# Select html filter to affect html table

Tags: html, filter, drop-down-menu

I am creating an html table using render template and loading the data via it. I need to create a drop down filter from a column of that table. And once the selected option is availed, it should store to a variable and should affect the html table in display.

This is the code i used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Criticality Assignments</title> 
        <style font-size:16px;>    
        </style>
    </head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel/1.1.0/dist/jquery.table2excel.min.js">
    </script>
    
    <button id="dwnldBtn">
                Download Excel Sheet
    </button>
    <button class="btn" type="button"  onclick="window.location.href='{{ url_for('index') }}';"> Back to Main Menu
    </button>
    <br>
    <h1>Criticality Assignment Information (CDE Template)</h1>
    <br>
    <style>
        #dwnldBtn{
            background-color: green; 
            color: #fff; 
            padding: 10px; 
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px; 
            margin: 2rem 0;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
    <style> 
        table, th, td {border:1px solid black;} 
    </style> 
    <body> 
         <select name="System", id = "System">
          {% for item in items %}
          <option>{{item[0]}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
          </select>
          <p>
            You have selected: 
            <span id="selected"></span>
          
          </p>
       
 
            <p id="correct"></p>
            <button id="submit">Submit</button>

        <table id="System" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <thead> 
                <tr>
                    <th>CA Name</th> 
                    <th>CA Asset ID</th> 
                    <th>CDE</th> 
                    <th>CDE Asset ID</th> 
                    <th>PDE</th> 
                    <th>PDE Asset ID</th> 
                    <th>PDE System Name</th>
                    <th>GMIS ID</th>
                    <th>Completeness</th>
                    <th>Specificity</th>
                    <th>Conformity</th>
                    <th>Reference</th>
                    <th>Uniqueness</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>    
            <tbody>
                {% for item in items %}
                <tr> 
                    <th>{{item[0]}}</th> 
                    <th>{{item[1]}}</th> 
                    <th>{{item[2]}}</th> 
                    <th>{{item[3]}}</th> 
                    <th>{{item[4]}}</th> 
                    <th>{{item[5]}}</th> 
                    <th>{{item[6]}}</th>
                    <th>{{item[7]}}</th>
                    <th>{{item[8]}}</th>
                    <th>{{item[9]}}</th>
                    <th>{{item[10]}}</th>
                    <th>{{item[11]}}</th>
                    <th>{{item[12]}}</th>
                </tr> 
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>    
        </table>
        
        <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            let chosen = "Your answer is: ";
            $("#submit").click(function () {
                const vals =
                      $("#System").find(
                        "option:selected"
                      ).text();
 
                $("#selected").text(vals);
        
            });
        });
        </script>

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#dwnldBtn').on('click', function () {
                $("#System").table2excel({
                    filename: "CDE Template.xls"
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

I need the filter captured to a variable and able to filter the table via variable